# Android application to backup list of installed applications

Tags: android, backup

I want to backup applications list in one device and then restore some of these applications on other device or on same device. E.g. it must to save links to Google Play or some other way, so that restoration process must be simple.

Without root access, free and without big (full-screen) annoying advertising.

Comment: Can't [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en_US) be used to do so?
If so, can anyone share the task please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**[App List Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.punsoftware.backup)** does this. From the app's description:

> Saves the list of installed apps so you can re-download them from Google Play Store later (on the same or another device).

App lists can be saved to SDCard. There's a free version, but there are also two paid versions of it with extended functionality. No root required AFAIK.

However, these solutions would only cover apps installed from *Google Play* – if you've loaded apps from other sources (e.g. *F-Droid* or *Aptoide*), they might not be covered.

If you want to cover more, **[Adebar](https://github.com/IzzySoft/Adebar)** might be worth a look – provided you have ADB tools available on your Linux computer (there's an article for a [minimal installation of ADB](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/42474/16575) at our sister-site). This little tool creates scripts to backup your apps and data, plus additional details, so you can restore them to the same or another device. Disclosure: I'm the author of it, and I've written/used it to "partly clone" my working device (which I had to send in for service) to another one. It's still in early stage, so feedback is welcome :) *Adebar* is free, no ads, and works without root (with root you've more covered of course, like configuration files which cannot be accessed otherwise).

Comment: yes, direct `adb backup` and `Adebar` are betters answers.

Comment: Thanks! Just be aware that apps can "opt-out" from ADB Backups (and several do). But without root, there is no way around that.

Comment: Link no longer available for App List Backup, Adebar repo archived :\

Comment: Adebar repo archived **at Github,** yes. Follow the link given there. It's archived because GH does not allow disabling PRs etc. Development happens at Codeberg now, whenever there's a release that still gets mirrored to Github.

Answer (score 4):

Tried the ones listed in this thread, but they only save the package name and the list should be fed to the same app for reinstallation. Finally ran into [List My Apps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.onyxbits.listmyapps) which is capable of exporting to the following formats:

- Plain text
- HTML list
- BBCode list
- Markdown list
- Market URL
- Any custom format, defined through the build-in template editor

> *And, to the respect of the developer, the app doesn't require any permissions at all.*

#### Using `adb`

If you have [**`abd`**](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) installed then you can easily generate a list of installed packages (from a desktop computer when the phone is connected) with:

```
adb shell pm list packages
```

The command will also work directly on an android device when launched from a [terminal](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=terminal&c=apps):

```
pm list packages
```

Once you have the package names you can easily build the play market links (provided that the app was installed from the play market), i.e. for the Youtube app — `com.google.android.youtube` the play market link will be `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube`.

If you want to display the actual APK location along with the package name then you can use:

```
adb shell pm list packages -f
```

Comment: adb is a good answer because you're not depending on some random 3rd party app that does who knows what. I used `pm list packages -f -i -3` to show only the stuff I've manually installed and also show which app I used to install it (eg. Google Play, F-Droid, etc). Depending on just `list packages` by itself with no options could be difficult to know what app it is because the Java naming often doesn't match the app name and the app may not be in the Play store.

Answer (score 2):

[My App List](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projectsexception.myapplist) is what you can try, it does exactly what you asked for.

> With 'My App List' you can save installed applications in a list to
>   restore them after flash or install a new ROM.
>
> First you create a list of your installed applications. You can select
>   which applications do you want to save. The application create an XML
>   file in your external storage.
>
> Next you make a fresh install of your favorite ROM.
>
> Finally install 'My App List', load the XML file and install the
>   applications from the list.

It's free to use, and root access is not required.

The app list can also be shared/exported into different file formats.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ShareMyApps](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mattlary.shareMyApps):

- free
- generate a list of installed applications with links to Play, which you can share by email
- no need for root

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AppBrain](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps&hl=en):

- free
- generate a list of installed applications
- no need for root
- [can bulk restore](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/28087/12202)